# Couldn't deploy GAE (Google App Engine) application (Java SDK)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I was trying this quick start but I couldn't deploy the app. I made Google Cloud Platform account, cloud platform project and app engine application.
I used `mvn appengine:update` command.

Result was

```
[INFO] Running -A masas-first-project -V masas-first-project1 --oauth2 update /home/masa/Code/googleAppEngine/java-docs-samples/appengine/helloworld/target/appengine-helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT
The following URL can be used to authenticate:
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&client_id=550516889912.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
Attempting to open it in your browser now.
```

And it was like
[I don't know where to paste code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUIDB.png)

Comment: At last could deploy...
By using command "gcloud app create".
First I went along with Japanese quick start.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart
And I got same similar error but I read error message of maven ("mvn appengine:deplpy").

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) The current Google Cloud project [testproject-218805] does not contain an App Engine application. Use `gcloud app create` to initialize an App Engine application within the project.

Here is another good resource...
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/371

Thanks LOL.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer and accept it for future reference. I see you shared a token in a screenshot, you should obscure it since it grants the access.

Comment: Ok I will.
Post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

At last could deploy...

By using command "gcloud app create".
Maybe I made gcp project, but not gcloud app yet.

First I went along with Japanese quick start but I tried English one next.
[cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart)

And I got same similar error but I read error message of maven

```
mvn appengine:deplpy 
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) The current Google Cloud project [testproject-218805] does not contain an App Engine application. Use gcloud app create to initialize an App Engine application within the project.
```

Here is another good resource... [github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/371](http://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/371) Thanks LOL.

By the way I wrote about this at my weblog. But in Japanese..
I have also English contents. Visit [https://lavilleeternelle.wordpress.com/2018/10/08/gae-google-app-engine%e3%81%a7%e9%81%8a%e3%81%b6/](https://lavilleeternelle.wordpress.com/2018/10/08/gae-google-app-engine%E3%81%A7%E9%81%8A%E3%81%B6/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to paste that code into your terminal in order to authenticate.

Comment: Which command to use?
Any of them?
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/

Comment: This should only happen the first time you deploy, since gcloud needs to authenticate your credentials with your project. You can do this manually by using the Cloud SDK (gcloud CLI):  `gcloud auth application-default login` . The quickstart (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart) documents the steps and installations needed.

Comment: Will try.
GAE or GCP are a little bit complicated structure.